# On account pages , In My order section Print order page not showing order detail

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.1.3, magento-2.1.7

In  Customer account . All order are showing correctly and And when I get on specific order it aswell showing its detail but  when I click on print my order . Page is shown like this. Item order record and amount is not showing.  Why this happening any idea ? or where is this file I can get to check ?

[image: MY orders print section]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was due to a magento 2.1.7 issue ; and its fix is I think M2 sale module given wrong block class for sales_order_print.xml

Temporary way:

```
open [module-sale] view -> frontend -> layout -> sales_order_print.xml.
```

then modify line 20

```
<block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\PrintShipment" 
    name="order_items" template="order/items.phtml">
```

to

```
<block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Items" 
    name="order_items" template="order/items.phtml">
```

Then it will be fine.

If you are using custom theme just override the layout file to hotfix it. (no need change M2 source code)

If you have same error in future and didn't solved, kindly ask me.

[Reference on magento2's github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10530#issuecomment-325634092)